# Can an Exception thrown by something else cancel an async task?

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception

Let's say I have this Java code that does something asynchronously:

```
public String main() {
    try {
        // Code before that could throw Exceptions

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {...});

        // Code after that could throw Exceptions
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (CompletionException e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If this were to run and the Async task successfully starts executing, will it still complete even if something else throws an Exception? If not, how can I let the async call finish executing while the Exception gets thrown?

Comment: If the exception is thrown outside the async task it shouldn't affect the task itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If this were to run and the Async task successfully starts executing, will it still complete even if something else throws an Exception?

yes. The task is not interrupted.

NOTE: If your program exits as a result of an Exception, then the task will be stopped.

> If not, how can I let the async call finish executing while the Exception gets thrown?

It does this by default.

If you want to cancel the task however it might ignore the interrupt.

```
public String main() {
    CompletableFuture future = null;
    try {
        // Code before that could throw Exceptions

        future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {...});

        // Code after that could throw Exceptions
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        if (future != null) future.cancel(true);
        // ...
    } catch (CompletionException e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But the OP wants to know if an exception thrown outside the async task can interrupt the async task itself. The question is not about interrupting the task manually, it's about continuing to execute it even if an exception gets thrown.

Comment: @BackSlash I assumed the first question was rhetorical, but you have a point. Added both questions to make it clearer.

Comment: It's not just the first question. The second question is: *how can I let the async call finish executing?* and you answered with how to stop the async task manually, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BackSlash Good point. I missed that the OP is asking how to do something it does already rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the task has already started, any exceptions thrown after the call to  `runAsync` will not affect that task.

Exceptions propagate up the call stack. A call stack is local to a particular thread. As your task is running asynchronously (i.e. on another thread), there is no way for an exception thrown on another thread to affect it.